# vague convergence $\mu_{n}\overset{\nu}{\rightarrow}\mu$ implies $\mu(\mathbb{R})\leq\liminf_{n}\mu_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading about convergence vague. As a comment it says the following:

$\mu_{n}\overset{\nu}{\rightarrow}\mu$ implies $\mu(\mathbb{R})\leq\liminf_{n}\mu_{n}(\mathbb{R}).$

I'm trying to prove this but I don't get it.

The definition given is: Let $\mu_{n}$ and $\mu$ be finite measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}).$ If $\mu_{n}(a,b]\rightarrow\mu(a,b]$ for every finite interval which $\mu(\{a\})=\mu(\{b\})=0,$ then $\mu_{n}$ converges vaguely to $\mu.$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: *Hint.* Let $C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \mu(\{x\}) = 0\}$ and notice that $C$ is neither bounded from above nor from below. Then for any $a < b$ in $C$, we have $$ \mu((a, b]) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n((a, b]) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mu_n (\mathbb{R}). $$ Now what happens if $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to \infty$ along values in $C$?

Comment: Thanks to answer @SangchulLee. Because of the continuity of the measure we have the desire inequality. My doubt is how to prove that $C$ is unbounded. For sake, if $C$ is bounded from above, there exists $y=\sup C,$ so for all $b\geq y,$ $\mu(\{b\})>0$ but i don't know how to find a contradiction.

Comment: In fact it follows from a very strong claim that the complement of $C$, i.e. the set of all atoms of $\mu$, is at most countable.

Comment: @SangchulLee This is because a sum of nonnegative terms is finite implies only countably many of those terms are nonzero?

Comment: That’s correct! :)

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your help and time! :)

Comment: @Hasse1987 Thanks for the comment. It was very helpful.